# jQuery - Alter URL on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've grabbing the URL of a thumbnail when clicking on it and adding it to another image in the HTML:

```
$('#result .thumb').live('click', function() {
    var newImgSrc = this.src;
    $("#thumbnail").attr("src", newImgSrc);             
});
```

However I want to alter the URL that gets sent, it currently looks something like:

```
...com/4100/5412955054_45ce3a897e_s.jpg
```

I want to remove `_s` from the very end of the URL. Can I do this in jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use replace() function.

```
newImgSrc = newImgSrc.replace(/_s\.jpg/,'.jpg');
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, although I think it should be: newImgSrc = newImgSrc.replace(/_s\.jpg/,'.jpg'); - as the "_s" should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method + regex. Or slicing two last chars before dot and extension.